Adding columns to existing CSV in PowerShell
I'm attempting to take data from a CSV file that already exists and put it into a new CSV with additional columns added through PS.
Existing CSV (firstlast.csv)



First Last




John Doe


Jane Doe



I want to add 2-4 more columns to the CSV with headings that require spaces in them. All the data in each column will be the same though. For example:
NewData.csv



One Street
First Last
New Address




X Street
John Doe
Mary St


X Street
Jane Doe
Mary St



Here is what I've tried:
$Name = Import-Csv C:\firstlast.csv | Select-Object -Property *

$test = @{'One Street' = 'X street' ; 'First Last' = $Name ; 'New Address' = 'Mary Street'} | Select-Object -Property One Street, New Address
$test | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Export-Csv C:\NewData.csv


See the conceptual about_Calculated_Properties help topic. Also, use either ConvertTo-Csv (for in-memory CSV data generation) or Export-Csv (for writing to a file).

Import-Csv "C:\firstlast.csv" |
Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers @{'One Street' = 'X street' ; 'New Address' = 'Mary Street'} -PassThru |
Export-Csv "C:\NewData.csv" -NoTypeInformation


Nice. We could add a | Select to adjust the column order if needed:
Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers @{'One Street' = 'X street' ; 'New Address' = 'Mary Street'} -PassThru |
Select 'One Street','FirstLast','New Address' | Export-Csv "C:\NewData.csv" -NoTypeInformation```

You're kinda close, what you're missing is a loop to enumerate each row from firstlast.csv and then you need to change the syntax in Select-Object, for the new rows and their value you can use what is known as calculated properties:
Import-Csv C:\firstlast.csv | Select-Object @(
    @{ N= 'One Street'; E={ 'X street' }}
    'First Last'
    @{ N='New Address'; E={ 'Mary Street' }}) |
    Export-Csv C:\NewData.csv -NoTypeInformation

If this syntax is hard to understand, what I prefer here is to create custom objects instead of using Select-Object:
Import-Csv C:\firstlast.csv | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        'One Street'  = 'X street'
        'First Last'  = $_.'First Last'
        'New Address' = 'Mary Street'
    }
} | Export-Csv C:\NewData.csv -NoTypeInformation

